# Autoloader for Propel 1.5.6 doesn't seem to fully work

Tags: autoload, propel

I have installed Propel 1.5.6 onto my Mac, running PHP 5.12.14 via MacPorts. I've created a schema, generated a model, run the sql generation and insertion tasks, and am moving onto the runtime stuff now.

I've got the following code to work fine (it creates a row and then counts the number of rows):

```
<?php

// Set up some paths & schema info
$projectPath = realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' );
$schemaName = 'database';
$modelPath = $projectPath . "/${schemaName}/build/classes";

// Init propel
require_once $projectPath . '/lib/propel-1.5/runtime/lib/Propel.php';
Propel::init($projectPath . "/${schemaName}/build/conf/${schemaName}-conf.php");

// Add the generated 'classes' directory to the include path
set_include_path($modelPath . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());

// This seems to be sufficient to get the autoloader working ***
require_once $modelPath . '/database/NodePeer.php';

$node = new Node();
$node->setName('My Node');
$node->setHash(sha1($node->getName()));
$node->save();

$nodes = NodePeer::doSelect(new Criteria());
echo 'Node count: ' . count($nodes) . "\n";
?>
```

However, if I remove the line with the starred comment, I would expect it still to work - I think the autoloader should kick in and load *all* the necessary model classes for me. However, I get this:

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant
>   'NAME' in
>   (project)/database/build/classes/database/om/BaseNode.php
>   on line 211

I've hacked the autoloader to echo the classes it loads, and found that it does indeed load some classes:

> Autoload: Node
>
> Autoload: BaseNode

However, when it loads BaseNode, it struggles on a static reference to the Peer class. I find that this is the case if BaseNode is manually required as well.

- Is PHP struggling on my configuration to autoload statically called methods/constants?
- Or could there be a problem to do with the order in which the Propel autoloader loads things?

For the time being, I'll carry on as I am - it is no major issue to include the peer - but I'd like to know if I can get away without it. One less thing to think about!

Comment: Interesting. I've removed the require_once on the Peer class, and removed the four lines used to save a new model instance. This leaves the NodePeer::doSelect() _static_ call as the first instance PHP encounters that should trigger an autoload. However, it doesn't do this - no attempt is made to autoload anything at all. A PHP issue, possibly?

Comment: Answers still welcome, but please be aware I've cross-posted this to the official [Propel help channel](http://groups.google.com/group/propel-users/browse_thread/thread/e17fc9d333ad9ae7). Thanks.

Comment: This is solved. As per the discussion on the other thread, I discovered that there is a problem with the autoloader with model tables that clash with existing Propel classes (in my case, "node" generates a conflicting class called NodePeer). The solution is either to name the table something else, or to upgrade to PHP 5.3 and switch on the Propel namespace feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autoloader wasn't working in this case because my model generated a class that clashed with an interface provided by the Propel core. Renaming this would have worked, as would using the namespace system (though of course the latter is dependent on using PHP 5.3.+).